# Facebook JSON empty objects

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the JSON feed from Facebook, and I want all the posts, including pictures etc.

This is my attempt:

```
    var pageId = 'cocacola',
        baseUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + pageId + '/posts',
        accessToken = '121107811423598|UoKvqJ7F5LO95b_DCY_6QN9OMg8',
        fields = ['message','link','picture','updated_time'],
        getUrl = _generateUrl(fields,baseUrl,accessToken);

    var xhr = $.get(getUrl);

    xhr.done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

    function _generateUrl(fields,baseUrl,accessToken) {
        return baseUrl + '?access_token=' + accessToken + '&fields=' + fields.join('%2C');
    }
```

And so far it does give some results, but apparently if I take a look at their fb pake, they have a few public posts, and I would expect to see them in my response, but there are only 3 results, one of them is an empty object (empty: no relevant data)

Anybody can help me out with this one?

JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WT8RE/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `FB.api` of [facebook js sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)?

```
FB.api('/cocacola/posts?fields=...', function (result) {
     console.log(result);
});
```

edit: i've tested you JSFiddle and it does work... i gets the public posts...

Comment: thank you for your response, it does work, but its not reflecting the actual public posts on their page.